# VLC output to DirectShow source filter

Tags: video, directshow, video-capture, vlc

See: https://superuser.com/questions/653725/vlc-output-to-directshow (Reposting here because it's not getting much attention over there, and I'm open to writing software to solve this problem if required.)

The short version: I want a virtual DirectShow Source device (something that looks like a webcam or similar) that instead of using a real device will obtain video & audio frames from VLC as it plays through a playlist.  (Thereby allowing another application that only understands webcams to see the content.)

I'm open to writing some code if required (though this seems like the sort of thing that ought to exist already) or to using something other than VLC if that simplifies things.

I haven't written code for DirectShow or VLC before, but I'm open to learning.  Or if anyone can point me at something suitable that already exists (whether as an app or as code), that would be preferable.  However this is a hobbyist thing so I'm not looking for anything expensive.

Answer (score 2):

To inject the data into DirectShow pipeline you need a custom built or third party component. There is no standard component for this task. The closest Windows SDK sample doing the data injection is [Push Source Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is a source of data on its own, and it is extended into being a device other applications can recognize in [Capture Source Filter](http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm) project here. These are the popular starting points.

On the other end such component needs to get data from VLC. Since it is another application, there is a need to do a sort of interprocess communication there. Perhaps the easiest is - esp. if you don't have specific requirements for the quality and latency - to set up network streaming on VLC so that the streams could be read using well known protocols over sockets. This also leaves you an option to have the apps running over network. Having it standard protocol streaming you could possibly find an existing filter for the task in paragraph above (and avoid development).

Stricter requirements in one of the following: latency, image quality and/or frame rate, video/audio synchronization, target application fitting, smoothless seeking or effects - basically anything from the list might still require integration through development, or reading the files directly without VLC at all. For a hobby thing you might be fine building it on existing stuff though.

Comment: I've discovered that the end application is more restrictive than I thought.  I built the PushSource example and registered it but it did not appear as a valid source in the app.  I'm guessing it's looking specifically for capture devices somehow rather than general sources.

Comment: I gave you the second link above which features the project that does appear on the list of devices. It's basically `PushSource` + added required interfaces (`IAMStreamConfig`, `IKsPropertySet`) + proper registration under device category.

Answer (score 0):

Existing solution - [VisioForge Virtual Camera SDK](http://www.visioforge.com/virtual-camera-sdk.html). It includes 2 filters, one filter is sink, that must be used as output for VLC player, second filter - virtual camera device.

Comment: I'm not sure if VLC has an option to output to DirectShow.  Or at least if it does I don't know where it is.

Comment: Also, a 300 euro price tag does not fit into my definition of "hobbyist".